# Get data by comma seperate with same UserId

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table which have following fields.

- ID = Bigint (PK)
- USERID = bigint
- Area = Varchar(50)

Now Every User have 3 Areas in table (So there are 3 entry for USERid with different Area).

[image]

I need output as below:

[image]

Now In report I want to Display USERID and all Area with comma separated associated by his UserID as above.

I try with group by but I did not find any help.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL-Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For MS-SQL Server 2008, you can use the following XML hack.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.USERID, REPLACE((
            SELECT Area AS 'data()'
            FROM table1 a
            WHERE a.USERID = t.USERID
            FOR XML path('')
            ), ' ', ', ') AS Areas
FROM table1 t
```

A little bit better would be to use `STUFF` instead of `REPLACE`

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.USERID, STUFF((
                SELECT Area AS 'data()'
                FROM table1 a
                WHERE a.USERID = t.USERID
                FOR XML path('')
                ) , 1, 1, '') AS Areas
FROM table1 t
```

If you have a lot of functions where you need to use this and there is a performance issue, then you better have a look at the **[GROUP_CONCAT string aggregate for SQL Server](https://groupconcat.codeplex.com/)**. 
This is a T_SQL function, you can download it from CodePlex [here](https://groupconcat.codeplex.com/releases/view/106409).

Comment: Just be aware of **Spaces** in you fields. It might break the code.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, you can group your results by their `USERID` and and then use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to concatenate all `Area` in the group. Something like this:

```
SELECT USERID, GROUP_CONCAT(Area) FROM table1 GROUP BY USERID;
```

For SQL Server, you might want to take a look at [Simulating GROUP_CONCAT MySQL function in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am using Sql Server 2008

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server. this might help

Answer (score 0):

select UserID,Area= ( SELECT Area + ',' 
                from #table1 A1
                where A.UserID =A1.UserID
                FOR XML PATH('')
                )
from #table1 A
GROUP BY A.UserID